# jQuery: Timeout/Delay with a notification function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, debugging, timeout, delay

I wrote the following simple function that takes two parameters mostly coming from another function returned with json from the server.

```
var timing = 10000;

function notificationOutput(type, message) {
    console.log('output now!');
    var note = $('.notification');
    note.css('display', 'none');
    if ( type == "success" ) { note.removeClass('warning').addClass('success'); }
    if ( type == "warning" ) { note.removeClass('success').addClass('warning'); }
    note.find('.message').html(message);
    note.slideDown( function() {
        note.delay(timing).slideUp();
    });
}
```

All it does is simply sliding down a bar from the top of my page putting out a message (either success or warning). The `timing` variable is for the notification-bar to stay for 10 seconds. So when the function is triggered I want the bar to `slideDown()`, hold that position for 10seconds and than `slideUp()` again.

However right now when the function is triggered there is a weird timeout happening till the notification bar appears. That means when the function is fired the `console.log()` output I have in there right now is logged immediately in my JS-console but the slideDown() takes a few seconds longer to appear! Why is that?

I want the `slideDown()` to happen immediately (at the same time as the `output now` is logged in the console). Why is there a delay happening?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: side note: `note.slideDown().delay(timing).slideUp();` would also work. No need to use the finished-callback here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing obvious there. I would try trimming the code down until it slides down as expected. Remove the callback, remove the html-set, remove the success/warning class-setters, select the note-element before outputting to the console, replace the slide with an immediate show, etc.

---

Also try calling `.stop(true,true)` on the note first: `note.stop(true,true).slideDown();`. This is in case it is busy with some other animation and the slide down is being queued.

Comment: weird, that `note.stop(true,true).slideDown()` did the job. When I set it to just `show()` it did work without a problem. Don't know where this queuing could come from. Any ideas?

Comment: Not really. Maybe some other animation is being attached to it accidentally. If you really want to know, then I would remove/disable as much as possible of everything else until it works as expected.

Comment: hey, another question. I have the same problem with the `delay()` function … event thoug the `timing` variable is set to 10000 the notifcation stays only for 3seconds or so.

Comment: Maybe there is something else interfering? Hard to say without a test case.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
note.slideDown().delay(timing).slideUp();
```

Answer (score 0):

i think that the problem might be in the `easing` function used by the slideDown which is `swing` by default (which is logaritmic). try using linear and maybe try using a faster slidedown time

```
note.slideDown(400, 'linear').delay(timing).slideUp(400, 'linear');
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing a value for `duration` to `slideDown`. Try:

```
note.slideDown(1000, function() {
  note.delay(timing).slideUp();
});
```